# Sorting a DataTable using custom function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am working with [DataTables plug-in](https://www.datatables.net/) in JavaScript.

Usually, if I need to update a cell value, I use the [`cell().data(set)`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.data%28%29) method followed by [`.draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29).

However, I do not want to use this way because my table contains heavy DOM object. So, when I need to update a cell, I just call some jQuery like `$("#cell").attr("myattr", 50)` for example, and then I managed to never have to use `draw()`. This prevents the object to be rebuilt each time, but unfortunately it also means that the DataTable is not aware of these changes (`cell().data()` returns the unchanged object).

This is a problem when I want my table to be sorted. In fact, the sorting is performed on the data that the datatable known, data which is not changed.

So I thought I could use the [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option, implementing a function like this:

```
function(data, type, row, meta) {
    if (type === "sort") {
        return $("#cell").attr("myattr");
    }
    return data;
}
```

This does not work and I think this is because of the fact that DataTable [caches the data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.cache%28%29). So, as I never update cells data, cache never need to be updated, and sorting is done using this cache, which does not correspond the cell `myattr` attribute.

**I am looking for a workaround which can allow me to sort a DataTable even if cells values are not changed internally but from outside.**

Play with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5rbsg98/3/), clicking the "CHANGE VALUES" button and trying to sort the column, you can see that the values are not correctly ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple solutions:

> **SOLUTION #1**

Use [`cell().invalidate()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.invalidate%28%29) API method to invalidate data in cache as shown below:

```
$('#example').DataTable().cell($("#a").closest('td')).invalidate('dom').draw(false);
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5rbsg98/4/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

You can use [`columns.orderDataType`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderDataType) to specify name of custom ordering plug-in, see [Custom data source sorting](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/#Custom-data-source-sorting). These plug-ins can access live DOM content.
Please note that there are no plug-ins built into DataTables, they must be added separately.

You can use [`dom-text`](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-text) plug-in as a base and write your own function to access the data for sorting.

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5rbsg98/5/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of these solutions. This is very useful, thank you very much!

Comment: @Delgan, thanks for adding the second demo, glad that it worked for you.